# How do I position a div relative to a fixed position div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I am wondering how to position a div relative to a fixed position div within the same parent div. Here is my html structure:

```
<div class="container">

  <header class="site-header>
  </header>

  <div class="site-page">
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
div.container {
 max-width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 auto;
}

.site-page {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
}

.site-header {
 width: 80%;
 text-align: right;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 float: right;
}
```

So, how would I make the .site-page class relative to the bottom of the .site-header class?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'd like a header/nav fixed to the top of the page and another div fixed to the bottom of the header/nav.

Comment: that means the second div fixed on the bottom like footer right ?

Comment: No, floating in relation to the bottom. Fixed to the bottom of the header/nav

Comment: is that what you need the below answer is right ? please check with it

Comment: set margin-top or padding-top

Comment: This is what I was doing to achieve the aesthetic, but thought there would be a better way for implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `margin-top` or `padding-top` the amount of height of the fixed element. I have used padding instead of margin, because the height increase on the div can be countered with `border-box`.
Or if you choose to do it with margin, then use `height: calc(100% - AmountOfHeader)`.

Also, there is no such thing as `padding: auto`, it's either `0` or a positive value.

https://jsfiddle.net/8evLtbgr/

```css
div.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  
color: white;
}

.site-header {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}

.site-page {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  
padding-top: 100px; /* height of header */
background-color: green;
}


/***********/

body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; margin: 0; } /*need this, because page is empty*/

*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* padding and border won't increase size of the elements, namely .site-page */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header class="site-header">site-header</header>

  <div class="site-page">site-page</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works and is what I was doing earlier, but I thought there had to be a better way to do this so I don't have to change the margins for different screen sizes.

Comment: If you'd use javascript/jquery, you can check on load, on resize events, and adjust it from there. So, get the height of the header and change the top padding of the page div with that value.

Comment: Thanks pol, I am trying to do this now but have run into some issues, will create a new post since it is somewhat unrelated to the original question now.

Comment: Thank you I just wasn't including jQuery properly in my WordPress theme.